# How do you change last names in SharePoint?

Tags: display-name, user-profile

I am new to Sharepoint Administration and we are running version 12.0.0.6318.  We have two people who recently got married that I need to change their last names.  Their information has been changed in the Active Directory but SharePoint is not in sync with it.  Can you tell me how this can be done?  Any help you could give will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using regular Windows Sharepoint Services (WSS) then you would need to go to the User Information list (Site Actions, Site Settings, People and Groups, All People), select the user and edit their display name.  You would need to do this on each Site Collection since there is no centralized profile.

If you are using a version of Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server (MOSS) you have the ability to change go into the User Profiles and edit the user's profile.  Normally this is picked up automatically though during a profile synchronization with Active Directory (when properly scheduled).

[All features in WSS exist in MOSS, plus many more.](http://teamsandtools.com/Tools/sharepoint.html)

Comment: Additionally, if Active Directory pass-through authentication is enabled already (sounds like it is), OP can delete the user account from the relevant site collection user list, and the next time they login a new account will be automatically created with their new name from AD.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the 2003 days I wrote a webservice that helped a lot with this type of situation.

Here is a code sample:

```
public void UpdateUserInfo(string userId, string basepath, string displayName, string emailAddress)
{
    SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri(basepath));
    SPSiteCollection siteCollections = webApp.Sites;

    foreach (SPSite siteCollection in siteCollections)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb)
            {
                SPUser user = web.SiteUsers[userId];
                if (displayName.Length > 0)
                {
                    user.Name = displayName;
                }
                if (emailAddress.Length > 0)
                {
                    user.Email = emailAddress;
                }
                user.Update();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (siteCollection != null)
            {
                siteCollection.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When customer service uses our internal tool to change a user's name or e-mail, the webservice would be called on all of our farms.  Depending on the size of your farm, you want want to mark this webservice oneway.

This method gives instant gratification for our users instead of having to wait for the MOSS profile sync, which for us is an incremental every night and a full once a week.

Answer (score 1):

Users will only be synchronised if they have been active within the site collection in question.  If the two users were to perform a 'contribution' to the site (i.e. update a list item or check out a document) then the next sync should carry across their new names.

There is an isActive flag on users and this must be set for their profiles to sync, hence the need for some form of 'contribution'.  Just visiting the site is not enough.

More info from @AndrewWoody can be found here:
http://www.21apps.com/sharepoint/user-profiles-why-do-my-changes-not-show-in-other-sites/